# Css rule for comments inside html code tag?

Tags: html, css

How to set a css rule so I can format comments inside html code tags?
something like regex //.*

```
<pre>
  <code>
    git reset [file]        //unstage but preserve file content
    ...
  </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: You cannot do that by CSS.

Comment: I want to change the color of comments

Comment: CSS does not 'understand' text content within an element. You will have to write some code (e.g. in Javascript) to parse the code elements and work out what text seems to be comment in whatever language it is you are showing within the code element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can put the comments in tags:**

```css
.comment {
  color:grey;
  /*Your CSS here*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://css-library.hg0428.repl.co/script.js"></script>
<pre>
  <code>
    git reset [file] <span class="comment">//unstage but preserve file content</span>
    ...
  </code>
</pre>
```

If you dont want to use tags then you will need to use JavaScript to loop through all the code tags, locate comments, and apply the class.